# I can signal the demise of the world, or I may be the key to unlocking it

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

*I may have four legs, or I may have none-*
*I may have two ears, but perhaps I cannot hear.*
*I may have two eyes, but could it be that I cannot see?*

*Either way, I can be found in your home;*
*Either way, something trails behind me.*
*Either way, some may touch me while others refuse.*

*Maybe I can eat, but maybe I cannot.*
*Maybe I rely on shadow, but perhaps I rely on light.*
*Maybe I am scorned, but I can also be loved.*

*I can signal the demise of the world,*
*Or I may be the key to unlocking it.*
*Do you know of whom my tale speaks?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be a

> Mouse (small mammal)

but maybe you are a

> Mouse (computer accessory)

I may have four legs, or I may have none-
I may have two ears, but perhaps I cannot hear.
I may have two eyes, but could it be that I cannot see?

> the first possibility always refers to the mammal, the second to the computer mouse

Either way, I can be found in your home;

> OP probably lives somewhere where mouse infestations are more common

Either way, something trails behind me.

> tail or cord

Either way, some may touch me while others refuse.

> mice (especially the furry ones) scare some people

Maybe I can eat, but maybe I cannot.

> same pattern as before

Maybe I rely on shadow, but perhaps I rely on light.

> mice hide in the darkness, an optical mouse uses light to detect its position

Maybe I am scorned, but I can also be loved.

> mice are considered pests, but sometimes kept as pets

I can signal the demise of the world,

> rats and mice seem to have taken cities over in almost every post-apocalyptic movie

Or I may be the key to unlocking it.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXgXA4VlStE

Do you know of whom my tale speaks?

> Not really, no.

Comment: That is indeed what I was thinking of when I wrote the riddle :) Good job~

Comment: The last one is about the tail too?