# A small problem

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's an original I just came up with. Enjoy

> You pay to get rid of me, yet I'm not free
>
> I move on a wheel, yet a wheel moves in me
>
> I'm not a good pet, yet you have me at home
>
> Chop off my tail and I'm free to roam

What am I?

Comment: Darn it, out of upvotes.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment :)

Comment: Nice riddle, there's some [slight sense of Déjà-vu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/68077/36023) though. I think I like this version better though, so +1.

Comment: I love this riddle, especially its twists! $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ $(+1)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it a

> Mouse?

You pay to get rid of me, yet I'm not free

> If you have a mice infestation in your house, you pay to get rid of them. A mouse is not free (pet mouse or computer mouse).

I move on a wheel, yet a wheel moves in me

> You may have a pet mouse wheel, and a computer mouse has a wheel in it.

I'm not a good pet, yet you have me at home

> Most people have a computer mouse at home.

Chop off my tail and I'm free to roam

> Maybe a reference to a wireless mouse?

Comment: Nicely done! And welcome to the Puzzling SE, by the way. Not a bad way to start off!

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Garbage bag?

You pay to get rid of me, yet I'm not free

> You pay for your food, which becomes trash.

I move on a wheel, yet a wheel moves in me

> Garbage cans move on wheels, and then they are placed in garbage trucks. Wheelception.

I'm not a good pet, yet you have me at home

> It stinks.

Chop off my tail and I'm free to roam

> If you don't tie the bag it spills.

Comment: Nice interpretation, but not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Phone

You pay to get rid of me, yet I'm not free

> cancelling your plan costs money.  and the service is not free.

I move on a wheel, yet a wheel moves in me

> old time rotary phones can be thought of as having a wheel that moves

I'm not a good pet, yet you have me at home

> Everyone has a phone

Chop off my tail and I'm free to roam

> Wireless/Cell phones roam as their "tailed" wired counterparts couldn't.

Comment: Welcome to the Puzzling SE, and thanks for the participation! 

You are not quite there, but I like your explanation for the last line.... see what you can do with that